# Read HTML file using in C++ to extract content between <p> and <h3> tags

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Wilbur/HTML32.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Wilbur/HTML32.dtd">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body style="margin-left: 5%;">
    <a name="pagetop"></a>
    <a name="firstpage"></a> 
    <div>
    <h3>Content to read I</h3>
         <p>
Content to read II<br><br>
</p>
          <img src="abc.svg" width="200" height="166" alt="">
<br><br>    
<h4>Code:ABC</h4>
      <!-- End Buttons -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to read the content between the 2 tags < p > (without < br >) and < h3 >
Is there some standard available in lets say boost for achieving the same?

Comment: [Whatever you do, do not use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: That is the idea, using regex would be a very dirty method. I was wondering if I could use QTextDocument to extract the content between the tags. I am not very keen to use QtWebKit as it wont be supported in higher versions of Qt.

Comment: @user2695082 If you want to load the file as a webpage you can look at the QWebEngine as a solution. But if you are loading it as a simple file I don't think there is a standard Qt library. You would take a look at third-party libraries such as https://github.com/cutelyst/html-qt or https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser

Comment: I didnt use those, but they are proposed candidates , [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#details) , [QXmlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html)

Comment: I tried QXmlStreamReader, however I was only getting the head tag and nothing beyond that. More research on the same suggested that these are particularly XML parsers. For using these, we would need to convert html to Xhtml(valid html). After looking at several options, I was about to get the information I desire using QTextDocument and then extracted each text block using QTextBlock.

Comment: Here's one thirdparty library which can help with converting HTML to XML: [tidy-html5](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5). Used it myself for the this very goal, works yet not without a few glitches; [here](https://github.com/d1vanov/libquentier/blob/master/src/enml/HTMLCleaner.cpp) is an example of its usage in a Qt project, just in case.